# use preg_replace or htaccess to replace url string

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I am in a pickle. I just took over a new job and the old programmer inputted content into MYSQL using BLOB / bin.

There are 1000's of rows that I need to "find and replace" a new image url.

When i export the MYSQL database, I can't do a find and replace all, because the data is Binary?

I am not sure what my options are ?

I was thinking of using PHP preg_replace or try to code a .htaccess rewrite or redirect rule for these images ?

www.oldsite.com/images/

to

www.newsite.com/images/

I really don't know which way is better and more efficient?

I wish I knew how to find and replace all with Binary files or if it is possible ??

Thanks for any help or tips on this !

**EDIT**

Great! So I can do something like this

```
$myString = rawurldecode($offer['description']);
$newString = preg_replace('/www.myoldsite.com/', 'www.mynewsite.com', $myString); 
echo $newString;
```

**EDIT #2 and conclusion **

I ended up figuring out how to do a find and replace!! Thanks to @user113215

Ended up using this code below and it worked great!! Event with binary files!!

```
UPDATE table_name SET column = REPLACE(column_name, 'www.old.com/', 'www.new.com/')
```

Thanks! Hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: Consider directly modifying the database with `UPDATE` and MySQL's [`REPLACE()` string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). This might require using [`ALTER TABLE` to convert the character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html) of the column in question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Does this work for Binary files?

Comment: I'm talking about an SQL statement like `UPDATE table_name SET column = REPLACE(column_name, 'www.old.com/', 'www.new.com/')` that you'd run on the MySQL server, not against a file copy. This would modify the database directly. I'm not sure if you can use `REPLACE()` with a `BLOB` column, but if the data in that column is _actually_ a string, you could use `ALTER TABLE` to change the column type to `VARCHAR`, for instance, then run `UPDATE`.

Comment: Very interesting method. I didn't think of this! Then if I would run this, it would update the database?

Answer (score 1):

In the code, where you select the field to display it, use a str_replace.
When the code is any good, it has a getter for this field, or at least some central code to do the mysql select.
str_replace is fast, and doesn't take that many resources.

Comment: Great! So I can do something like this ( look up at edit i made )

Comment: For a simple replace as this, you dont need preg_replace, a str_replace is enough:
$url = str_replace('oldsite', 'newsite', $myString);